# How to redirect the output of vmrun.exe with listProcessesInGuest on windows?

Tags: io-redirection

I run vmrun.exe with listProcessesInGuest on the command line and get the list of processes displayed in the console window.
The exact command line is:

```
"C:\VIX\vmrun.exe" -T vc -h "https://myserver/sdk" -u "mydomain\myuser" -p 123 -gu Administrator -gp 123 listProcessesInGuest "[Storage1] QA-W-7-SP1-64-0/QA-W-7-SP1-64-0.vmx"
```

It works fine.

Now I wish to redirect the output, however, neither `2>` nor `1>` work! The former has no effect - the output is still displayed in the console window, so I conclude it is send to stdout. But the latter does not work too - now nothing is displayed in the console window, but the redirection file is empty! It is created all right, but it has the zero size!

Can someone explain what is going on?

**EDIT**

Piping to `more` displays nothing as well. Meaning

```
"C:\VIX\vmrun.exe" -T vc -h "https://myserver/sdk" -u "mydomain\myuser" -p 123 -gu Administrator -gp 123 listProcessesInGuest "[Storage1] QA-W-7-SP1-64-0/QA-W-7-SP1-64-0.vmx" | more
```

displays nothing. Remove the pipe and there you go - there is output.

**EDIT2**

Upgrading to the most recent version of vmrun solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The single pipe overwrites, so maybe it's that somehow - try with the double pipe - e.g:

```
"C:\VIX\vmrun.exe" -T vc -h "https://myserver/sdk" -u "mydomain\myuser" -p 123 -gu Administrator -gp 123 listProcessesInGuest "[Storage1] QA-W-7-SP1-64-0/QA-W-7-SP1-64-0.vmx" >> output.txt
```

Comment: >> has the same effect as 1>, namely blank output and the file is empty.